# How can I prevent the password from appearing in the network tab payload?

Tags: javascript, forms, xmlhttprequest

I am making a form using next js 14, I made an actions.ts file there I built a generic method that shows a console log.

[form component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BX8D2.png)

[action.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/48uIs.png)

In the form component, loginForm.tsx, in the form tag, I use the action property, and from there, I call the generic method that I made in action.ts

[devtools/network tab/payload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FlBp2.png)

What happened is that, when I clicked on the save button of the form, I observed that in the devtools, in the network tab, a request was reflected, but I saw that in the netowrk tab, in the payload option, all the information in the form fields is displayed.

my doubts are:

1. Why does the user and password information appear in the devtools -> tab network -> in the payload?
2. Is that considered a security vulnerability?
3. Is there any idea on how to prevent it from displaying that information?

I was investigating the topic, apparently it has to do with the html tag , but there was no mention of how to solve that detail

Comment: That won't be a problem if you send the request through the `https` protocol which encrypts the request. That doesn't make the request 100% safe but still, safe enough that even big applications such as Facebook or Instagram send the raw password to the backend. We never encrypt any data in the client because encrypting in the client can never be safe as the users can see the client codes, then reverse-engineer the encryption algorithm and decrypt the payloads of the other users. but the `https` is safe enough that attackers cannot easily get the requests' payloads.